# DateTime : Month Diffenece Formula in VB?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, formula, monthcalendar

I mean, how to write formula like this:

```
Dec2013-Feb2014, the result = 3 (from december to february, jump 3 time)

Jan2014-Feb2014, the result = 2 (from january to february, jump 2 time)

Feb2014-Feb2014, the result = 1 (in same month is 1 time)
```

then i have

> - TextBox1.text -> as month before
> - TextBox2.text -> as month after
> - TextBox3.text -> as the result
> - Button1.text, button to get the result in the Textbox3.Text
>
> If I write TextBox1.text = "20-May-2012", TextBox2.text =
>   "20-Feb-2014", I wanna TextBox3.Text = 22.
>
> If I write TextBox1.text = "20-May-2013", TextBox2.text =
>   "20-Feb-2014", I wanna TextBox3.Text = 10.
>
> If I write TextBox1.text = "20-Dec-2013", TextBox2.text =
>   "20-Feb-2014", I wanna TextBox3.Text = 3
>
> If I write TextBox1.text = "20-Jan-2013", TextBox2.text =
>   "20-Feb-2014", I wanna TextBox3.Text = 2
>
> If I write TextBox1.text = "10-Feb-2013", TextBox2.text =
>   "20-Feb-2014", I wanna TextBox3.Text = 1

and so on.

how could i write the month jumping formula?

Answer (score 1):

You can do by datediff function in VB.NET

```
Dim datTim1 As Date = TextBox1.Text
Dim datTim2 As Date = TextBox2.Text

Dim wD As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, datTim1, datTim2)

TextBox3.text = wD
```